# Sort_values for know created DF

Tags: python, sorting, data-science, decision-tree

I am trying to sort values descendingly for:-

```
FeatureImportances=pd.DataFrame(Tclf.feature_importances_,index=Name_features).sort_values(by='',axis = 0, ascending = False)
```

whenever I try to assign a feature"column" Name to the attribute 'by', it gives me an error
So, what to assign for the attribute 'by'!!

Comment: This would make your feature names as indices and a single column with the importance values. You needn't specify the by column since there is only one column or printout the column name and input that in your by parameter.

Comment: I didn't really get that. I have to specify the by argument, otherwise, it gives me an error -->"sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'"